# How to create a translate animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview, translation, cycle

Hi I am creating a game with three `ImageView`s that gradually move down and then when they reach a certain point the `ImageView`s return to the top of the screen and so the `ImageView`s move in a continuous cycle. I have tried using a translate animation to move the `ImageView`s around. However all the `ImageView`s remain stationary which means that I haven't set the the translate animation up correctly.

Here is the code that I have used (`speedtwo` is a `double`, and `timetaken` is a `long` that I set up)

```
    double speedtwominus = speedtwo * -1;

    final TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, (float) speedtwo);
    anim.setDuration(timetaken);

    final TranslateAnimation finish = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, (float) speedtwominus);
    anim.setDuration(0);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 
            numone.startAnimation(anim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            numone.startAnimation(finish);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
});
```

Comment: What is the value you're assigning to `speedtwo`?

Comment: Speedtwo is the total amount of pixels that I wish to move the top ImageView by.

Comment: Have you tried starting your animation on your `ImageView`s? For example, `imageView.startAnimation(anim)`. Also you might want to consider using the `setRepeat` feature for `Animations`.